# What differences are there in these git delete branch methods?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch, git-push

From [help.github.com](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote#deleting-a-remote-branch-or-tag) `git push` can be used in the following way to delete a remote branch:

```
git push  <REMOTENAME> :<BRANCHNAME>
```

> (...) you're telling Git to push nothing into BRANCHNAME on REMOTENAME. Because of this, `git push` deletes the branch on the remote repository.

However from [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch-Deleteanunneededbranch), this also deletes a remote branch:

```
git branch -d -r <REMOTENAME>/<BRANCHNAME>
```

Adding that:

> The next fetch or pull will create [it] again unless you configure [it] not to.

So would it be preferable to use one of these methods in a particular situation, or do they basically end up doing the same thing?

(Bonus point for examples:)

Comment: Thanks @phd actually [one of the answers in the question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23961231/1326147) explains that using `git branch -dr <remote>/<branch>` only deletes the *remote-tracking* branch and not the actual remote branch.

Comment: The answer also explains that manually deleting a remote branch through the github interface does not delete the *remote-tracking* branch in the local repo, requiring later a pruning or the `git branch -dr ...` method. So the fastest option seems to be the `git push <remote> :<branch>` method, deleting both *remote-tracking* and *remote* branches at the same time. I marked this question as a duplicate to redirect people to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23961231/1326147).